# Merge Two array in One and Try to show it on loop In laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to join two array in one array and use it on a loop

```
public function showJobCategoryContent($id)
{

    $jobsInfo= Job::where('category_id', '=', $id)->where('published', '=', 1)->paginate(3);
    $dateInfosById= $jobsInfo->map(function ($job) {
         return $job->created_at->addDays(30);
    });
    $array = array_merge($jobsInfo->toArray(), $dateInfosById->toArray());
    $myArray=json_encode($array);

    return view('front.category-content.job-category-content',[
        'jobsInfosById'=> $myArray

    ]);
}
```

When i am trying to show it on loop it shows ===Invalid argument supplied for foreach() anyone help me

front view code is

```
 @forelse($jobsInfosById as $jobInfoById)


                   <li>
                       <div class="well">
                           <h4>{{$jobInfoById->company_name}}</h4>                       
                           <h5 class="deadline">Deadline:<b>{{ date('d F, Y', strtotime($jobInfoById->date)) }}</b></h5>


                   </div>
                   </li>

                   @endforelse
```

[image]

Comment: no \@empty statement? Why @forelse then?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `json_encode`, because you must pass iteratable data to `foreach` amd not string created by `json_encode`:

```
$myArray = $array;
```

Comment: If i don't use it then it-- shows Trying to get property of non-object company_name

Comment: It's another issue. Since you're using array, you need to use `{{ $jobInfoById['company_name'] }}` syntax instead of `{{$jobInfoById->company_name}}`

Comment: Now it shows- "Undefined index: company_name " I know there is Index company_name

Comment: Do `dd($array)` to see it's structure.

Comment: Please see the Image

Comment: Iterate with `@forelse($jobsInfosById['data'] as $jobInfoById)`

Comment: Now it works but It shows only one array based on this variable $jobsInfo but how about $dateInfosById this variable data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159297/discussion-between-raz-biswas-and-alexey-mezenin).